# pandas: loss of precision when specifying seconds as floating point

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to create an datetime index with 5000 elements, an unknown offset and an unknown delta between the elements. The delta value and the offset are parameters and the only certainty is that they will be expressed in seconds as an integer or floating-point number.

I use `pd.Timedelta(value, "s")` to compute this delta (since `np.timedelta64()` does not accept floating-point values).

```
pd.to_datetime(1687957943.122, unit="s") + np.arange(0, 5000) * pd.Timedelta(0.002, "s")
```

unfortunately, the floating-point arithmetic causes loss of precision (the following numbers aren't exactly 0.002 seconds apart):

> array(['2023-06-28T13:12:23.121999872', '2023-06-28T13:12:23.123999872',
> '2023-06-28T13:12:23.125999872', ...,
> '2023-06-28T13:12:33.115999872', '2023-06-28T13:12:33.117999872',
> '2023-06-28T13:12:33.119999872'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

compare:

```
# offset manually upgraded to integer number and unit specified as ms
pd.to_datetime(1687957943122, unit="ms") + np.arange(0, 5000) * pd.Timedelta(0.002, "s")
```

this gets me the desired result:

> array(['2023-06-28T13:12:23.122000000', '2023-06-28T13:12:23.124000000',
> '2023-06-28T13:12:23.126000000', ...,
> '2023-06-28T13:12:33.116000000', '2023-06-28T13:12:33.118000000',
> '2023-06-28T13:12:33.120000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

However, since I don't know the time precision of the offset, I cannot simply do this.

I could probably write some code to determine the correct unit, but it feels like this shoudl be some built-in functionality already. Any clues? +1 if I don't need pandas at all.

Comment: But floating points are almost never exact (in the mathematical sense of "almost never": the probability for a number to have an exact representation in float is 0. Even if you had no limitations in number of bits for exponent and mantissa, that probability would still be 0. Practically no number have an exact representation in float. But a handful. Like numbers that are an integer divided by a power of 2)

Comment: I was aware of that, but apparently python `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` handles it just fine. See my answer :)

Comment: So, this has nothing to do with timestamp (tho there are less "9" or "0", in the approximation, I mean, you numbers looks like "23.1239998" or "23.1240002", not "23.123999999998" or "23.1240000000002", because the number are already very big. And the bigger the number, the more bits are used for the integer part, and the less bits for decimal part — it doesn't work like that; there isn't really a decimal and integer part; but the result is like that).

Comment: I guess it is just a matter of `round` vs `floor`. If you add `0.0000005` to your timestamp, (shifting things, so that in microsecond `floor(μ+0.5)` is the same as `round(μ)`, and `round(μ+0.5)` is the same as `floor(μ+1)`. Situation is reversed: instead of having first method returning `***000` half of the time and `***999` the other half, and 2nd method always returning `***000`, you have now first methond returning `***000` always, and 2nd returning `***000` half of the time and `***001` the other half.

Comment: A compromise seems to be adding 0.0000003. Then both method always returns `***000` microseconds. 0.0000003 is apparently enough to have the 1st method never going under the exact ms, and not enough to have the 2nd method sometimes going over the next exact ms.

Comment: @chrslg just using `fromtimestamp()` is the only non-hacky way I can identify

Comment: Note that with `float64`, aka `double` in C, which are obviously used here error for this kind of value is around `0.0000002`/`0.0000003`. Both method can't escape that (anyway it is the precision of python's native float, at least with most interpreter, and your start from that). And things will get uglier in 2038,

Comment: Yes, I am not suggesting to add 0.0000003. Else I would have put that in an answer, not in comments. I am just using this to reverse engineer what happens  under the hood, and to prove that it is a floor/round difference, probably.

Comment: (And not, for example, a situation where float128 are, quite magically, since, again, your input float, native python type, is probably a float64 anyway, used by one method and not the other)

Answer (score 1):

So the problem already starts at:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(1687957943.122, unit="s")
g.microsecond  # == 121999
```

You need to use the `pd.Timestamp.fromtimestamp()` function to avoid such behaviour:

```
g = pd.Timestamp.fromtimestamp(1687957943.122)
g.microsecond   # == 122000
```

As for the solution without pandas:

```
g = datetime.fromtimestamp(1687957943.122)
g = pd.to_datetime(g)
g.microsecond  # == 122000
```

I do wonder how it is done behind the scenes, but this answers the main question.